# Plotting a Bar Graph in python with Matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

```
   Groups   Counts
1   0-9     38
3   10-19   41
5   20-29   77
7   30-39   73
9   40-49   34
```

I want to create a bar graph using matplotlib.pyplot library with groups on x-axis and Counts on y-axis. I tried it out using following code

```
    ax = plt.subplots()
    rects1 = ax.bar(survived_df["Groups"], survived_df["Counts"], color='r')
    plt.show()
```

but I'm getting following error

```
   invalid literal for float(): 0-9
```

Comment: apparently (as the error message tells) the data type of your groups column is not compatible to a float. What is your datatype? string? what kind of object is `survived_df`. Do you use Pandas? then add it to the tags!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first array given to the `plt.bar` function must be numbers corresponding to the x coordinates of the left sides of the bars. In your case, `[0-9, 10-19, ...]` is not recognized as valid argument.

You can however make the bar plot using the index of your DataFrame, then defining the position of your `x-ticks` (where you want your label to be positioned on the x axis) and then changing the labels of your x ticks with your Groups name.

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(survived_df.index, survived_df.Counts, width=0.8, color='r')
ax.set_xticks(survived_df.index+0.4)  # set the x ticks to be at the middle of each bar since the width of each bar is 0.8
ax.set_xticklabels(survived_df.Groups)  #replace the name of the x ticks with your Groups name
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that you can also use the `Pandas` plotting capabilities directly with a one liner:

```
survived_df.plot('Groups', 'Counts', kind='bar', color='r')
```

[image]